# Advanced Find/Replace plugin successfully installed but I'm unable to use it

Tags: gedit, plugins

I just installed the [Advanced Find/Replace](https://code.google.com/archive/p/advanced-find/downloads) (Simply downloaded advanced_find-3.6.0.tar.gz, extracted it and used `bash ./install.sh` in the terminal) plugin for gedit 3.18.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It seems the installation was successful:[image]
Unfortunately, I couldn't find it anywhere in the bar in order to use it, even after restarting the computer:[image]

Could you please help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue for Gedit v3.12+. See here: [Support for Gedit 3.12](https://code.google.com/archive/p/advanced-find/issues/136). There is a possible fix here: [Can't load plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/advanced-find/issues/98).

By the way, the project looks outdated. The last release was 2013-05-01 for Gedit v3.8.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, the project is outdated. In your links, it is said that advanced_find-3.5.3.tar.gz is working fine. I installed it but it didn't work. When I looked in internet, it seems that the reason is that the loader is python. Choosing pyton3 instead doesn't solve the problem. I give up and uninstall it.